# convert pyspark dataframe to custom tuple

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that consists of id column and text column

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, ['Julia', 'is', 'awesome']),
    (1, ['Data-science', 'is','cool']),
    (2, ['Machine,learning,was,my,subject'])
], ["id", "words"])

+---+---------------------------------+
|id |words                            |
+---+---------------------------------+
|0  |[Julia, is, awesome]             |
|1  |[Data-science, is, cool]         |
|2  |[Machine,learning,was,my,subject]|
+---+---------------------------------+
```

I want to convert this into tuple. I used to do this using pandas dataframe. Below is the tuple

```
tup = []
for _,i in df.iterrows():
    tup.append((i['word'],{'text_id':i['id']}))
```

sample_output:

```
[(['Julia','is','awesome'],{'text_id': 0})]
```

How to achieve the same for the entire pyspark dataframe? Is there a way to do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use RDD transformation using `map()`.

```
# use RDD and map to create tuples
data_sdf.rdd. \
    map(lambda k: (k.words, {"text_id": k.id})). \
    collect()
    
# [(['Julia', 'is', 'awesome'], {'text_id': 0}),
#  (['Data-science', 'is', 'cool'], {'text_id': 1}),
#  (['Machine,learning,was,my,subject'], {'text_id': 2})]
```

Comment: what if the data is huge?  collect function brings the entire data to driver node right?

Comment: how do you want to use the tuples?

Comment: Will pass these tuples to spacy module

Comment: in that case, yes are right and you will have to use collect() for the tuples to be usable. unless the model can be sent to all executors. then, (I think) you can use forEach or map()